# Trouble with ASP.NET CAPTCHA Control Sample with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, captcha

I am trying to use the following [A CAPTCHA Server Control for ASP.NET - by Jeff Atwood](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/CaptchaControl.aspx) within an ASP.NET MVC site.  The custom control doesn't seem to be validating when the form is submitted.

Is there anyone who has done any work with this sample using ASP.NET MVC?

The basic code I am using is as follows:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
<CaptchaControl:CaptchaControl ID="CaptchaControl" Name="Security" runat="server"></CaptchaControl:CaptchaControl>
<input type="submit" value="Send Message" />
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really recommended to use ASP.Net server controls for an ASP.Net MVC site.  ASP.Net MVC does not execute the page lifecycle like regular ASP.Net does.  The server controls may render, but if they rely on ViewState or Postback events, they will not work.

Looking at the code for the Captcha Control, this seems to be the problem.  The validation is programmed to occur during LoadPostBackData.  Unfortunately, there is no concept of a postback in ASP.Net MVC... and hence no postback data.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a complete blog post about an ASP.NET MVC captcha control. Maybe it's worth to have a look at it, since it's very up to date:

[ASP.NET MVC Captcha Control](http://dustinmoris.com/asp-net-mvc-captcha-control-part-1)

Comment: Off topic, what blog software are you using, it's very clean.  I like it.

Comment: @dustin Instead of effectively just posting a link, could you post an excerpt inline here? We don't encourage link-only answers.

Comment: @Mystere Man: my own home brew ;)

Comment: @dustinmoris - by excerpt, he means a small portion of the article, not just using an anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

A better choice is to simply use the reCaptchaMvcExtensions from the NuGet package library.  This is a simple to install and use package that uses the full google reCaptcha.